# Check attribute href by jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Let my site be `http://cars.com`

I have links on my site, to `http://girls.com`, `http://google.com`, `http://happy.com`, etc.

Here is js:

```
$("#wrapper a").live('click', function()
{
    var this_url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: this_url,
        complete: function(){
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

So, when we click on a link, it loads html of that page.

How to:

1. get address of currently opened site? like `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` on php.
2. sanitize attribute `href`? such symbols like "`#, ?`" should be removed
3. check, if this `href` is an url (can be `/section/images/` or just `/`) to my site (`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`)? If not, do nothing (don't want to load html of other sites).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the [`location.host` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object).
2. Use a regex to parse the string.
   For example:

   ```
   var pathSection = /^[^?#]+/.exec(url)[0]
   ```
3. Check whether it starts with a protocol.  Use a regex like `/^\w+:/`.
   If you have absolute URLs to locations in your domain, you'll need to check for them separately.

Comment: Not all browsers support `location.domain`.  #3 also won't work if he has the protocol in the href of his own site, which is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible for security reasons the restriction is called [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) or short SOP. You can bypass this by proxying the request via a server side script.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question.

Comment: he tries to perform an AJAX request to the url declared in the link and the links point to foreign domains so he will run into the SOP problem. But you're right a comment instead of an answer would have been more appropriate. Means +1 for your answer.

Comment: @ Happy: AFAIK there's no way to do it using plain jquery if the site you link to doesn't provide an interface like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). What you can do is proxying the request over a server side script (like loading the content using CURL and then return it). But this maybe a **huge** security risk and active sessions on the linked site will not be present of course.